# Jquery loading intermittently causing not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, loading

We have a JavaScript app that uses jQuery and has the following block that loads the libraries. This works ok most of the time but at random times the jquery-1.11.2.min lib seems to not load in time for the jquery-ui.min lib and so I get a ReferenceError saying that jQuery is not defined in the jquery-ui.min lib.
As far as I know the libs should load sequentially so I'm not sure why this happens so any ideas would be great:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        paths: {
            "libs": location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + "/js/lib",
            "actions": location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + "/js/actions"
        },
        packages: [
            { name: "jquery", location: "//code.jquery.com", main: "jquery-1.11.2.min" },
            { name: "jqueryui", location: "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3", main: "jquery-ui.min" },
            { name: "moment", location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + "/js/lib/moment", main: "moment" }
        ]
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Whats doing the actual loading? It's probably a problem with that. Does it respect your order? Does it account for one request taking longer than another?

Comment: I think you need to a dependency from the jqueryui package to the jquery package. I don't know the best way to do that because I don't know dojo.

Comment: Does the problem still exist if you try loading from a local file rather than the CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is with the `async:true` property

jqueryui have dependency with jquery therefor you **must** load jquery and then jqueryui when it's async it can load jqueryui and then jquery, that will throw an error

**edit1**
if you wish to continue using the `async:true` property then try yo use the [deps](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dojo_config/) property

**from site:** *deps: An array of resource paths which should load immediately once Dojo has loaded:
    deps: ["dojo/parser"]*

**deps** *(array of module identifier strings) / callback (function)*
These configuration variables are only applicable before the loader has been loaded. When provided, they cause the loader to execute require(deps, callback) once it has finished loading.

Comment: Setting this to false is generally a poor idea as it impacts the script in general (freeze page while it executes)

Comment: Thanks for this, really useful